# Meaning of "the field in which I grow my [expletive]"

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, idioms

Lately, I read the following sentence:

> Behold! The Field In Which **I Grow My Fucks**

On the first I understood it as if it meant:

> Behold! The Field In Which **I make my own business**

The reason why I thought this is that, in my native language, the expression:

> I make my fucks

or better

> I make my dicks

means

> I make my own business

or better

> it is my business, not yours

Anyway, I suspect that the sentence of which I'm talking about doesn't have the same meaning.

You can please help me to grasp its meaning.

Comment: You can look it up, it ain't carrots. And it's not an expression, fyi.

Answer (score 16):

It is likely referring to ***giving a fuck***, which is a derogatory way of saying ***to care (about)***. For instance, saying:

> I don't give a fuck / I don't have any fucks to give

means one does not care about the subject at hand.

The sentence could be a sarcastic way of saying they don't give any fucks, if the field which they are "growing their fucks" is completely empty.

It could also imply that they have a limited number of "fucks to give", which would mean they could only care so much about certain things.

Comment: The full meme is "Behold, the field in which I grow my fucks. Lay thine eyes upon it and thou shalt see that it is barren." That is, see my collection and that I have none to give, so I don't give a fuck.

Comment: This is not about giving a fuck, it's about growing them. Your 12 upvoters are delusional.